# SharePoint 2010 licensing for MSDN subscribers

Tags: sharepoint-2010

on our MSDN subscription we have Enterprise CAL license for SharePoint 2010. 
We developed our issue tracking system and we are ready now to publish it online, however only employees ,around 40, are allowed to access the website.(non of the website content is public-facing).

I'm wondering if this license is enough or we do need to buy per user licenses ?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like a question for serverfault.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Microsoft documentation on licensing for SharePoint 2010:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Licensing-Details.aspx

Licensing for SharePoint can be complicated.  If you are using Enterprise features such as Excel Services, BDC, Visio Services, etc. then you will need a server license plus an individual CAL for each user.  You may be able to subtract any MSDN licensed user from the total number of CALs you purchase.

May be worth a conversation with your Microsoft sales rep to be sure on pricing and the number/type of licenses you need.

Answer (score 1):

If all those 40 people have MSDN subscription, then it's enough.
If not, you will need a server license for each SharePoint server and 40 client access license.